# Questions about Visit Monitoring in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-location

I'm developing a journaling APP for iOS 9 or later using the Visit Monitoring feature to register user location through the day.

After a few days testing the feature using three devices (one using iOS 10 e two iOS 11) I didn't saw any visit recorded.

Looking to "Frequent Locations" is possible to see new updates coming, unfortunately none to my APP. Looking for internet examples I changed some things but without success. So, I have some questions about Visit Monitoring:

- In some web examples the ***startMonitoringVisits*** method is fired from AppDelegate. On the same way, AppDelegate became the CLLocationManager *delegate*. In my APP this method was fired after the user tap a specific button in main screen. My CLLocationManager instance and delegate was kept inside a singleton.
- Once I trigger the ***startMonitoringVisits*** method the location icon never disappear. This is the expected behavior? Why not the "Frequent Locations" work in this way?

BTW, I enabled background location updates and Always authorization was set.

Comment: You only need to call `startMonitoringVisits` once, and it can be done whenever/wherever you want in your app - so, in response to pressing a button is fine. But, in order to receive every visit event, you should always create a `CLLocationManager` instance and assign it a delegate during app startup.